# The new child element contains the parent JS error

Tags: javascript

I encountered a little problem. I have:

`html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chart.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
    <title>Chart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="lifespan-chart">
        <div id="lifespan-chart-content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`javascript:`

```
class Polyline {

    constructor(input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.nodes = this.convertNodes(input["nodes"]);
        this.color = input["color"];
        this.width = input["width"];
        this.height = input["height"];

        if (input["fill"] === undefined) {
            this.fill   = "";
        } else {
            this.fill   = input["fill"];
        }
        if (input["stroke"] === undefined) {
            this.stroke   = "black";
        } else {
            this.stroke   = input["stroke"];
        }
        if (input["stroke_width"] === undefined) {
            this.stroke_width   = "1.5";
        } else {
            this.stroke_width   = input["stroke_width"];
        }
        // for (var key in input) {
        //     console.log(input[key]);
        // }
    }

    changeParams(input) {
        if ("nodes" in input) {
            this.nodes  = this.convertNodes(input["nodes"]);
        }
        if ("color" in input) {
            this.color  = input["color"];
        }
        if ("width" in input) {
            this.width  = input["width"];
        }
        if ("height" in input) {
            this.height = input["height"];
        }
        if ("fill" in input) {
            this.fill   = input["fill"];
        }
        if ("stroke" in input) {
            this.stroke = input["stroke"];
        }
        if ("stroke_width" in input) {
            this.stroke_width = input["stroke_width"];
        }
    }

    convertNodes(list) {
        let result = "";
        let i = 0;
        while (i < list.length) {
            result += list[i];
            result += ",";
            result += list[i+1];
            result += " ";
            i = i + 2;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    setSvg() {
        this.svg = `
<svg height='${this.height}', width='${this.width}'>
    <polyline points='${this.nodes}', style='fill:${this.fill}, stroke:${this.stroke},stroke-width:${this.stroke_width}' />
</svg>
        `;
        //console.log(this.svg);
    }

    loadChart() {
        var div = document.getElementById('lifespan-chart-content');
        div.innerHTML = this.svg;
        document.getElementById('lifespan-chart-content').appendChild(div);
    }   

}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    input = {
        "nodes" : [0,0,50,50,100,100,200,200,300,300,350,350,450,500,550,650],
        "color" : "red",
        "width" : 500,
        "height": 300,
        "fill" : "bisque",
        "stroke" : "orange",
        "stroke_width" : 2
    };
    
    p1 = new Polyline(input);
    p1.setSvg();
    p1.loadChart(); // ??? error on this place 
})
```

And everything is ok, but when I want to add block to html in function `loadChart` I see an error in console:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent. at Polyline.loadChart`. What I should do to avoid such an error? I commented a place where error occures. Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1 : Forgot to execute `setSvg` before `loadChart`, I added it above, now it draws ok, but error is still here. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the div `lifespan-chart-content` to itself.

This will append a div with only the svg to `lifespan-chart-content`

```
loadChart() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.svg;
    document.getElementById('lifespan-chart-content').appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: same error, but if I write your code it won't show me my polyline

Comment: @WhoAmI, I updated my answer with new code, this will overwrite `loadChart`